# Metrics logging in Springboot to Signalfx using management.metrics.export.signalfx

Tags: java, spring-boot, metrics, spring-micrometer

I am calling a third party API using the
`org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate`
in my application.yml file
`management.metrics.export.signalfx.enabled:true`
we have 2 type of api call
`/api/users/update`
`/api/users/byUserId/123`

in the signalFX the first one is showing the count of call correctly but for the second one as the URI has the last 3 digit which changes based on the ID i count is not proper what we want is  that irrespective of the ID the count should show the the number of time the second URI is called. we want some metrics customisation that we can apply.

Answer (score 0):

The change that we did for this is that instead of call the restTemplate method with the URI having the ID we actually used

`restTemplate.delete("/api/users/byUserId/{id}", Collections.singletonMap("id", id));`

using this we were able to group the metrics with the URI /api/users/byUserId/{id}.